# Shell Script that create log if file is not send to remote server

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh, scripting, rsync

I have this small script which basically do rsync of files between to remote server. ssh key has been generated for authentication.

only this is present in the script

```
rsync /root/Desktop/cpfies/files/*.xls user@host:root/Desktop/cpfies/moved
```

basically what I want to create is a log method for this script not to fancy or anything ...only this... if the connection is lost and the file is not sent it comes in my log saying "File not sent connection not established"

also if the files has been sent it shows me in the logs successfully sent.

or if the host or the user is wrong it show in my log.

Thanks and Regards,
Sagar Mandal

Comment: Is the normal output of `rsync` okay? Then you can just redirect it (including `stderr`) to your logfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log only unsuccessful attempts, you can get rsync return value by looking into `$?`, which is the return value of the last script. `rsync` returns 0 on success and non zero on different errors (https://lxadm.com/Rsync_exit_codes). I would to it in that way:

```
#!/bin/bash

ret_text=$({rsync /root/Desktop/cpfies/files/*.xls user@host:root/Desktop/cpfies/moved} 2>&1)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo rsync error code $? on $(date)
    echo rsync output follows
    echo $ret_text
fi
```

You can put that into a `script` and when you run it, redirect its output into a log file like that `script >> log_file`, or you can just call script and add `>> log_file` after each echo command in the script.

If you want to log also successful attempts than you do

```
rsync /root/Desktop/cpfies/files/*.xls user@host:root/Desktop/cpfies/moved &>> log_file
```

or

```
rsync --log-file=log_file /root/Desktop/cpfies/files/*.xls user@host:root/Desktop/cpfies/moved
```

I would also suggest to increase the amount of information that rsync produces by adding `-v` or `-vv`. It is also possible to use `-vvv` or even more, but manual says it is for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try this and will let you know :-)